# Sylius ResourceBundle: how to override a Form service?

Tags: php, symfony, resourcebundle, sylius

In ResourceBundle, I've configured a resource "charge.quote" :

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        charge.quote:
            classes:
                controller: ChargeBundle\Controller\QuoteController
                model: ChargeBundle\Entity\Quote
                repository: ChargeBundle\Repository\QuoteRepository
                form:
                    default: ChargeBundle\Form\QuoteType
```

I'd like to know how I can override the form service, generated as charge.form.type.quote by ResourceBundle. The aim is to be able to access to the Service Container from QuoteType.

I tried to declare an other service to override the service generated by ResourceBundle, like this:

```
<service id="charge.form.type.quote" class="%charge.form.type.quote.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    <tag name="form.type" />
</service>
```

But the custom Form become ignored: ResourceBundle generate a generic form, from the Entity.

Any idea to pass the Service Container to my form class?

Thanks !

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 I don't understand what you mean. "charge.quote" is the id of the resource (more exactly, an alias), not the form itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue was recently solved here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3843

In short answers taken out from the issue:

You just define a service with same name, so app.form.type.book for example and give it an alias app_book. Sylius will use it from now. :)

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        zdg.registration:
            templates: EGBundle:Backend/Registration
            classes:
                model: ZDG\EGBundle\Entity\Registration
```

Services:

```
services:
    zdg.eg.type.registration:
        class: ZDG\EGBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: zdg_registration }
        arguments: [@doctrine, @sylius.context.locale]
```

Your form type name must match the alias. add to your Type:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'zdg_registration';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the "alias" property was missing on the tag : <tag name="form.type" alias="charge_quote" />

Comment: I believe the service should be named `zdg.form.type.registration` per this comment: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3843#issuecomment-170513903